# Loop to create dataframes from two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to read in multiple files in a directory into individual dataframes, but I need to make the name of each dataframe a substring from the original filename.

```
# master list of substrings to look for in filename
sub_list = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR']

# set path
path = 'C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/my_folder'

# get list of files with full path
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xlsx'))

# empty list for extracted substrings
df_names = []
```

Below is how I am extracting the substrings from the filename

```
for filename in files:
    if any(sub in filename for sub in sub_list):
        name = [sub_str for sub_str in sub_list if(sub_str in filename)]
        helper = '' # empty string to join with list element to convert to string
        name = helper.join(name) # convert list element to a string
        df_names.append(name)
```

I iterate over the `df_names` list to create dataframes

```
for name in (df_names):
    exec('{} = pd.DataFrame()'.format(name))
```

However I'm not sure how to add the actual data to these dataframes. I assume there is another way to do this, but haven't been able to figure out how. Maybe using dictionaries?

I've tried the following, but this overwrites all previous names and leaves me with one dataframe named `name`.

```
for name, file in zip(df_names, files):
    name = pd.read_excel(file)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered storing your dataframes in a dictionary instead of in a list?

Instead of:

```
for name, file in zip(df_names, files):
    name = pd.read_excel(file)
```

You could use:

```
dfs = {}

for name, file in zip(df_names, files):
    dfs[name] = pd.read_excel(file)
```

You could then get the dataframe for file 'ABC' (assuming 'ABC' is a filename) like this:

```
dfs['ABC']
```

Comment: Thanks @Charlie Hill, this works great. I'm still trying to learn about dictionaries!

Comment: @m8_ They're the best!  If you can get comfortable with them, they'll save you a lot of time.  This tutorial makes it easy: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out